# mvc3 - how do i trigger framework validation prior to submission so that it also displays error messages for required fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that is used like a wizard using JQuery. The only problem I have is that the user can click the next button to go to the next wizard step but the validation does not capture any required fields unless a user has edited the data. So, if you just click next, it does not pick up the errors or show any error messages. If i put a value in the input field and then remove it, an error is shown prior to submission.

How can I force the framweork validation to execute and find required fields that have not been touched?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the click of the "next button" simply call the Validate method of jquery validation plugin. (assuming you are using unobtrusive validation of mvc)